# PHP isset needs to be if not set

Tags: php

Alright, I have this:

```
$pg_id = isset($_GET['pg']) ? intval($_GET['pg']) : 1;
if($pg_id == -1) {
   $pg_id = -1;
   $pg_max = -1;
} else {
   $pg_id = $pg_id - 1;
   $pg_max = 12;
}
```

Basically this says if the "all" in paginate is clicked, to list all the items, otherwise it paginates and only shows a couple per page.  However, I need to I guess wrap this in an if/else statement to show all to begin with.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question. What is it that you're actually asking? Please clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!isset($_GET['pg']) || (int)$_GET['pg'] == -1) {
    $pg_id = $pg_max = -1;
}
else {
    $pg_id = min((int)$_GET['pg']), 1) - 1;
    $pg_max = 12;
}
```

Comment: @stillstanding, Yeah, I guess I my mind is always running in 1,000,000 directions when I am trying to post these questions. I'll work on phrasing them much better.